# Validating XML files against XSD in FireMonkey

Tags: xml, delphi, firemonkey, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I am developing a cross-platform application (for Windows, Mac etc.) and for 32-bit and 64-bit machines.
I have lots of XML files which I need to validate against their **XSD**.

Is there any way of doing this in Delphi XE3?

I have tried DTD validation but I'm always getting a "DTD prohibited" error. I have also tried solutions mentioned on lots of websites to resolve this error, but I've had no success.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I've used...

```
function TForm2.ValidateXML(const xmlFile : TFileName) : boolean;
 var
 xmlDoc: TXMLDocument;
begin
result := false;
  xmlDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil) ;
  try
    xmlDoc.ParseOptions := [poResolveExternals, poValidateOnParse];
   try
      xmlDoc.LoadFromFile(xmlFile) ;
     xmlDoc.Active := true; //this will validate
     result := true;
   except
     on EX : EDOMParseError do
     begin
     ShowMessage('Invalid XML: ' + Ex.Message) ;
   end;
   end;
 finally
   xmlDoc := nil;
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you need a cross-platform validator.

Maybe [Libxml2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2) (http://xmlsoft.org/) is an option, as it can be used from many programming languages on many platforms.

A open source Pascal wrapper for Libxml2 is avalaible on http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxml2-pas/

Comment: Thanks for response.i have tried on said website but it seems there is no example for Delphi.

Comment: Thanks.I have used that but getting access violations at start up.

Comment: @user2531352 then this should be a new SO question